# Will jQuery work on a CD distribuited "website"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cd

Sadly I have to make a website (so to speak website) that can be placed on a CD.
My question is, can I use JavaScript and jQuery?

Some of the people who get the CD might have IE6 on Win XP installed.

Thank you.

Comment: Some browsers block script execution on local content

Comment: I gave you a pity +1

Comment: Yes, you can. JS is a client-side language so, as long as JS will be enabled on the browser, everything will be ok. Oh, and regarding IE6... life's hard :p

Comment: why don't you create a tiny html file, save it locally and try it :) I would do that myself, but luckily Ubuntu doesn't know the concept of IE :)

Comment: Yeah, I would too, but I can't find any XP machines and my laptop CPU doesn't like virtualization.

Comment: Thanks, corroded, I'll give that a try. Left or right?

Comment: If you need to support IE6, you **NEED** a way to properly test it in IE6. Do it often while you're developing. It's horrible when you only check it at the end and find there's an overwhelming amount of issues to fix.

Comment: will the user be completely offline?   if so you'll need to include the Jquery .js files with your cd bundle and reference them explicity rather than linking to an online version as is often done.

Comment: hell if it was me id do both. maybe you could insert a script there targetted at IE users to give them a zillion js alerts that says: "TO CLOSE THIS, SHUT DOWN YOUR COMPUTER AND UPDATE YOUR IE"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a website on to CD, and javascript/jquery should work fine. But beware that you'll only be able to have static resources: that is every request must be for a physical asset that exists on the CD. I.e you wont be able to have pages rendered dynamically in response to a request, and I'm pretty sure that you won't be able to make ajax requests too.

Comment: I hope they enjoy their slick new 1995-style website

Comment: Thank you. No AJAX here, just neded some animations and sizzling DOM manipulation.

Comment: Ah, those were the days, ey Alex?

Comment: @Francisc: there's no reason that the site will have to look old-school, you can use modern css, javascript etc to make it look as glossy and as whizzy as you like. You're just limited to static pages that is all.

Comment: I know Richard, just liked Alex's comment. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. jQuery explicitly supports IE6, and IE6 supports JavaScript (it would have to, otherwise jQuery couldn't support it) although it has some bugs.

Comment: That will depend on the specific details of implementation - for example, anything requiring a server (like AJAX) will most probably not work.

Comment: @Francisc — Use relative URLs. You have no idea where the CD will be mounted.

Comment: Thank you, jcinacio and Quentin.

Answer (score 2):

I had experience of making such a thing. It was a catalog of goods. So I grab all data and converted it to JSON. The catalog itself was only one page which show the goods using JS and client-side templating, doing some sorting and search. The biggest problem with using this catalog was that fact that reading much of small files from CD is really slow. So it was necessary to use as much CSS-sprites as possible instead of regular set of good's photos.